# IE8 CSS Right Float Breaking Parent to the Left

Tags: .net, css, html, internet-explorer-8

I have an issue with the following code and compatibility with IE8 (the original code is more complex but this shows the bare bones of the issue)

```
Protected Sub btnExpand_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    If btnExpand.Text = "Expand" Then
        btnExpand.Text = "Collapse"
        lblContent.Text = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    Else
        btnExpand.Text = "Expand"
        lblContent.Text = "Content"
    End If
End Sub

<style type="text/css">
    div {padding:10px; margin:20px;}
    .Section {width:550px;}
    .ClearBoth {clear:both; padding:0px; width:490px; margin:0px;}
</style>

<div>
    <div class="Section" style="float:left; background-color:Green;"></div>

    <div class="Section" style="float:Right; background-color:Blue;">

        <div style="background-color:Yellow;"></div>

        <div style="background-color:Red; display:inline-block; float:right;">
            <div style="background-color:Orange; display:inline-block;">
                <asp:Button ID="btnExpand" runat="server" Text="Expand" onclick="btnExpand_Click" />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="lblContent" runat="server" Text="Content"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="ClearBoth"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ClearBoth"></div>

        <div style="background-color:Fuchsia;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

A user click on the 'expand' button and more information is shown in the orange DIV (note: the orange DIV is actually invisible, it's the red DIV we care about in this example)

In the real code clicking on the 'expand' button un-hides about 10 columns in a gridview, in this example we're just putting a ton of X's into a label but the result is the same.

The red DIV expands (to the left) to show the now visible content.

I created this code with Chrome as my default Browser, This code also works well in my backup browser (IE10) however this code doesn't work in our company Browser (IE8)

In IE8 both the orange and red DIV's expand to the right of the blue parent DIV regardless of the fact that the red DIV is set to float:right.

Considering this works in Chrome and IE10 I'm assuming my code is right for this moment in 'Dev Time' and forwards but does anyone know of any way to get this working for IE8? I spent a good 4 hours yesterday reading W3C documents on floats and display and searching here and google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming as no one has come up with an answer for this it's an IE8 issue and can't be solved, especially as IE10 works correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `overflow:auto` to the parent.

Comment: Tried that, it stops the ability for the red div to break out of it's parent giving the look that the red div has been cut in half for some reason

Comment: so try `overflow:visible` and `text-align:right` to the parent, and remove the `float:right` from the sons (while keeping `display:inline-block`).

Comment: That has the effect of right aligning the orange div (something I don't want to do) and now it expands to the right and not the left in chrome. In IE8 the 'added' content breaks all the divs.